# My SharePoint list shows profile picture in the Gallery view but not in the form?

Tags: sharepoint-online

My SharePoint list shows profile picture in the Gallery view but not in the form.
How can i solve this? I have used JSON code.

[image: screenshot]

Gr. P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried the same in our SharePoint environment and found the same behavior - Profile picture of user is not shown on the display form of list item:

[image]

However, it shows the user profile pictures in edit mode (new form or edit form) when I search for user names:

[image]

---

If the profile picture of users were showing on the list forms previously and if you think it is a bug/issue from Microsoft end, you can raise a support ticket with Microsoft directly and report this behavior. Follow: [Get M365 Support - Online Support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/get-help-support?view=o365-worldwide#online-support)

Also, make sure "Show profile photos" is set to "Yes" in person column settings (modern experience):

[image]

I think you have already set it to "Yes" as you can see the profile pictures in the list view.